# A question about bijective functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f: [1,3]$$\rightarrow$$[0,8]$ is continuous. Show that there is some $x$$\in$$[1,3]$ such that $f(x)+4=4x$.

I need some advice on how to get started. Do i need to use IVT for this problem? Do I need to show that f is increasing while x is increasing?

Comment: **Hint** draw $4x-4$

Comment: I'd guess looking at $g(x)=f(x)+4-4x$ would be fruitful.

Comment: Is f _onto_ $[0,8]$, or just $f(x) \in [0,8]$?

Comment: Onto is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h(x) = f(x) - 4x + 4$. $h$ is continuous on $[1,3]$. Moreover:

$h(1) = f(1) \ge 0$ and $h(3) = f(3) - 8 \le 0$ since $\operatorname{Range}(f) = [0,8]$.

Thus, by IVT..

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Let $h(x)= \frac {f(x)+4}{4}: [0,8] \rightarrow [0,8] $ with $f:[1,3] \rightarrow [0,8] $ as given.

Then $h(x)$ is a continuous map from a compact convex set to itself, and so it has a fixed point *, so that there is $x$ with $h(x)= \frac {f(x)+4}{4}=x  $ , so that $$ f(x)+4 =4x  $$ has a solution in $[0,8]$

*:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem . Note that we only need the map to be *into* and not *onto* $[0,8]$. Note that the map is into but  not onto.

Comment: Maybe a different perspective, but , yes, simpler is better. Maybe good as a refresher, or practicing to have it in the toolbox.

Comment: @DavidMitra : Please see edit, I wrote that map must only be into, not onto.

Comment: @Surb : Yes, letme look into it.

Comment: @Surb: yes, I meant to work with $ f \circ f $ but got side-tracked.

Comment: @Surb: yes, I meant to work with $ f \circ f $ but got side-tracked. I mean, I want to work with $ g \circ f$ : g(x)=x :$[0,8] \rigtarrow [0,8]$.

Comment: I mean the range of $4x-4$ is $[0,8]$. Then , for g continuous and into $[0,8]$ , $g \circ f$ is a continuous function from $[0,8]$ to itself , with a fixed point. Maybe it will work, or I will delete.

Comment: @Surb: Please see my last edit; this is what I meant to write .